# How can I change the first line of multiple files including the name of the file?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have many files in a folder named as:

```
ctg_1.fasta
lcd2_13.fasta 
..
etc (all of them are .fasta)
```

I want to change the first line of each them to include the following: `>ctg_1`, `>lcd2_13`. I mean, that each file has its own name as the first line.

I think the command `sed` would help me. I tried to execute this:

```
var=">ctg_1"
sed -i "1s/.*/$var/" ctg_1.fasta
```

And it works, but I would like to do it recursively and that each file includes its own name.

Do you have any idea about how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67477734/3832970) work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` to get all the files recursively. Extract the filename without `.fasta` suffix from the variable with the filename, and use that in the `sed` command.

```
find . -type f -name '*.fasta' | while read -r f; do
    base=$(basename "$f" .fasta)
    sed -i "1s/.*/>$base/" "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel sed -i '1s/.*/>{}/' {} ::: *.fasta
```

The `-i` option results in the amended file being done in place and each file will have its own line numbers thus `1s/.*/>{}/' replaces the first line of each file by a` >`and the`{}` is the file name obtained by the parallel command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU `awk`:

```sh
awk -i inplace 'FNR==1{a=FILENAME;sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", a);print a}1' *.fasta
```

Details:

- `-i inplace`  - inplace replacement
- `FNR==1` - if the current line is the first
- `{a=FILENAME;sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", a);print a}` - assign the file name to `a`, remove the last dot and all text after it, and print the result
- `1` - default print action.